# Using a .NET COM DLL in C++ Builder 4 - Ambiguity between Strings and System::Strings

Tags: .net, dll, c++builder, ambiguity, mscorlib

I've created a .NET COM DLL that I need to use in my C++ Builder 4 project. I'm able to import the DLL using the Import Type Library functionality (in fact I import the TLB file that comes with the DLL when I build it). This creates a Component_TLB.h in my C++ Builder \ Imports folder. I then #include this _TLB file in my project and I'm able to do the following:

```
TCOM_Create theDLL;
theDLL = CoCreate::Create();
theDLL->FunctionX(paramy);
```

This works as intended.

---

The Component_TLB.h created from the "Import Type Library" functionality includes (amongst other things) mscorlib :

```
#include "mscorlib_TLB.h"
```

...which seems to be a dependable of my DLL, here's what I've found in the comments:

```
// DepndLst: 
//   (1) v2.0 mscorlib, (C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\mscorlib.tlb)  **<---**
//   (2) v2.0 stdole, (C:\Windows\SysWOW64\stdole2.tlb)
//   (3) v4.0 StdVCL, (C:\Windows\SysWow64\STDVCL40.DLL)
```

The problem is that because this mscorlib is included in my project I can't use the "String" type like I used to be. The following line:

```
String abc;
```

..gives me the following error:

```
[C++ Error] Unit1.cpp(23): E2015 Ambiguity between 'String' and 'System::String'.
```

It looks like this mscorlib has its own String type or something... I've found:

```
extern const GUID IID__String;
```

and

```
extern const GUID CLSID_String;
```

I use the String type A LOT in my project, how can I "force" the compiler to use System::String without having to recode everything line with a String type or how could I work around this ?

Answer (score 2):

Use a namespace so these identifiers don't get added to the global namespace

```
namespace Mumble {
   #include Component_TLB.h
}
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion but I then get the following error: [C++ Error] utilcls.h(2332): E2029 'IDispatch' must be a previously defined class or struct.

Comment: Sorry, no idea what utilcls.h is.

Comment: It is include by mscorlib_TLB.h like this:   #include <vcl/utilcls.h>